# Android onNewIntent() notification is not acting correctly

Tags: android, notifications

I have a broadcast receiver for notification. My app is a webkit, and I want my app to be opened and directed to a certain URL when user clicks on the notification. Everything seems to be working fine, but I've encountered a problem now....

`onNewIntent()`is called if the user last exited the app by pressing home button. but `onNewIntent()` is not called if the user exited from back button. can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The home button doesn't (usually) kill your application, it just gets taken off the screen. Any intents sent to it would be sent to `onNewIntent()`.

The back button usually causes your activity to exit outright. Any intents sent to it would start it again from scratch via `onCreate()`.

Note that in general, any time your application isn't on the screen, it can be killed by the system to conserve resources. This means that your application must *always* be prepared to restart itself from `onCreate()`.  Whatever you're doing in `onNewIntent()`, you need to be able to handle it from `onCreate()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using working handling the intent in the onNewIntent() and in the onResume()...  if the app is coming in the onCreate() it probably doesn't have the data I need setup yet. Make sure you check for null to avoid NullPointerException.